# python telegram bot conversationbot horizontal buttons instead of vertical

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

In [this sample](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py), it show buttons like this:

```
Number1ToChoose Number2ToChoose Number3ToChoose Number4ToChoose Number5ToChoose
```

While I'm going to see this:

```
Number1ToChoose
Number2ToChoose
Number3ToChoose
Number4ToChoose
Number5ToChoose
```

I didn't find a way to do this up to now.

Comment: I don't see any buttons in that sample.  And, honestly, is it really worth the trouble, as long as the sample does what you need?

Comment: @TimRoberts by buttons, I mean the texts in `start()`  function and its `reply_keyboard` variable, which is not an actual button, but is like button. The sample works for me, but I'm just curios if it's possible, because I see some bots have something like this. I mean each index of `reply_keyboard` list is shown in one line to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you didn't really read the documentation or the source code.  The code looks like this:

```
async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    """Starts the conversation and asks the user about their gender."""
    reply_keyboard = [["Boy", "Girl", "Other"]]
```

The `reply_keyboard` is defined in the documentation as a list of rows.  What you have above is a list with one row with three buttons.  If you change that to:

```
    reply_keyboard = [["Boy"],["Girl"],["Other"]]
```

Then you'll get three rows with one button each.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I know the comment is spam, but I got it:) Thanks a lot.